# How to call AngularJS parent directive scope method from child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I have a parent modal directive with confirm and cancel methods.

```
        ngDialog.open({
            scope      : true,
            showClose  : false,
            template   : theTemplate,
            className  : 'ngdialog-theme-prompt -small',

            controller : ['$scope', function Ctrl($scope) {
                $scope.message = message;

                $scope.confirm = function(){
                    $scope.closeThisDialog();
                    resolve(true);
                };

                $scope.cancel = function(){
                    $scope.closeThisDialog();
                    resolve(false);
                };
            }]

        }).closePromise.then(function () {
            resolve(false);
        })
```

The template is another directive.

```
<form class="edit-stakes-content">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="stake in settings track by $index">
            <input type="number" name="input" pattern="^\d+$" min="0" value="{{stake}}" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="edit-stakes-control">
        <button ng-click="cancel();" class="apl-btn apl-btn-link apl-btn-large" translate>CANCEL</button>
        <button ng-click="confirm();" autofocus="true" class="apl-btn apl-btn-update apl-btn-large" translate>SAVE</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In the child directive of the modal i want to be able to perform some validation and POST to the server and then call the parent modal directive confirm or cancel methods.

Similar to this:

```
Directive.$inject = ['UserSettings'];

function Directive(UserSettings) {
    function Link($scope) {

        $scope.settings = angular.copy(UserSettings.get('presetStakeSettings').settings);

        $scope.cancel = $scope.$parent.cancel();

    }

    return {
        'link': Link,
        'restrict': 'E',
        'replace': true,
        'templateUrl': 'betting/edit-stakes/edit-stakes.html'
    }
}
```

Calling the parent method throws a JavaScript error that $scope.$parent.cancel is not a function yet seems to do the job.

Is there a better way to achieve the child to parent communication without the JavaScript error?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$parent` generally can be considered an antipattern, there are almost no good uses for it, usually it indicates that there is a problem with directive design or scope inheritance isn't well understood.

`Directive` directive doesn't request a new scope, so it is safe to assume that it is the same scope as the scope in modal controller. This means that `$scope.$parent` refers to a parent of modal scope (likely to root scope) which doesn't have `cancel` property.

This also means that `$scope.settings` assignment affects controller scope - while it obviously shouldn't. It would be better to have inherited scope in this directive with `scope: true`.

It doesn't matter if there is `scope: true` or not, but `$scope.cancel` will be available in directive. It is inherited from modal scope. There's no reason to do

```
$scope.cancel = $scope.$parent.cancel();
```